# Перенаправление на web страницу с Google forms

Tags: html, google-forms

Написал простенькую форму на html, что бы заносила данные в таблицу Google forms
Всё замечательно работает за исключением - после нажатия кнопки отправить
[image: html форма]
выскакивает
[image: Страница подтверждения с Google form]

Хочу что бы перенаправляла на мою страницу, такое возможно?
Подскажите пожалуйста решение? Спасибо.

html код формы, на всякий случай.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Форма заявки на поверку счётчика</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSdc4NJZ_sNXx3uicbDrRfRyaqPjG6IjpDCJsOkiXz-rQBz8Og/formResponse" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="entry.365460815" placeholder="Ваше Имя">
     <input type="text" name="entry.179395769" placeholder="Ваш Город">
     <input type="hidden" name="entry.1688570434_sentinel" placeholder="Ваш Город">
     <input type="text" name="entry.83959061" placeholder="Ваше отзыв">
     <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
 </form>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

так удалось решить вопрос.

```
<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;"     
onload="if(submitted) {window.location='/pay.html';}"></iframe>
  <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSdl4hJCvCiQ0f3JKyF0gZfWHN1m8w75Hj786tIQrSL2xxq3Ag/formResponse"
        method="post" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">
```